# Change css style in a specific time without refresh the page with ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie of ionic 1 and angular JS 1, I would like to change a colour of an icon when a specific time is reached without refresh the page.

My current code is as below :

```
    <button class="icon ion-ios-videocam" ng-style="iconstyle”>  </button>

    var currentTime = Date();
    var parsecurrenttime = Date.parse(currentTime);
    if (parsecurrenttime >= parseTargetTime) {
    $scope.iconstyle = {
    color: '#e42112'
    };
    }
```

May I know is there any idea how to achieve it without refresh the page ?

Many thanks.

Comment: When are you executing the js code?

Comment: you can use the angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$timeout` Service from angular.

Your code should look like this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.iconstyle = {
       color: '#e42112'
    };
}, 3000); //time in milliseconds = 3 seconds
```

The function will be executed after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be calculating how long you have to wait until the script should be executed and set timer to such interval. I see you are using AngularJS, so you have to put the below code somewhere in your controller.

```
var timeout = null;

// Clean-up
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
});

function changeColor() {
    $scope.iconstyle = {
        color: '#e42112'
    };
}

(function() {
    var interval = new Date(2016, 11, 27, 18, 0).getTime() - Date.now();
    timeout = $timeout(changeColor, interval);
})();
```

### Explanation

The first function is simply manipulating the `$scope` object. It is invoked by the timeout, which is set in the self-invoking function placed below. The self-invoking function will calculate the time needed to wait until the `changeColor` function should be called. In this case, the function will run at "2016-12-27 18:00". The timeout will be re-calculated on each controller instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it something like when page get loaded after 30 seconds button color get green.

```
    .goGreen{
    color:green;
    }

    <button class="icon ion-ios-videocam" ng-class='{goGreen:ifBtngreen}'>  </button>
    $scope.ifBtngreen=false;
var parseTargetTime=30000 //in milliseconds
    $scope.$on('$ionicViewEnter',function(){
     $scope.startTime()
    })
    $scope.startTime=function(){

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.ifBtngreen =true;
    }, parseTargetTime);
    }
```